# Oracle Join on V$ views becomes extremely slow when a temp table is used

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, oracle19c

I am trying to get some information from the Oracle V$ views

```
SELECT bpd.handle,bpd.media,bpd.copy#, bpd.bytes, bpd.session_key, bsjd.operation,bsjd.start_time, bsjd.end_time,bpd.completion_time,  
bsd.controlfile_included
FROM v$backup_piece_details bpd 
INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details bsjd ON bpd.SESSION_KEY = bsjd.session_key
INNER JOIN v$backup_set_details bsd ON bpd.set_stamp = bsd.set_stamp AND bpd.set_count = bsd.set_count
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ibpd.session_key, count (ibpd.handle) count FROM v$backup_piece_details ibpd 
INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details rbsd ON IBPD.session_key = rbsd.SESSION_KEY
GROUP BY IBPD.session_key, IBPD.handle) hc
ON hc.session_key = bpd.SESSION_KEY
```

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

https://pastebin.com/raw/QrkzeHH7

If I remove

```
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ibpd.session_key, count (ibpd.handle) count FROM v$backup_piece_details ibpd 
INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details rbsd ON IBPD.session_key = rbsd.SESSION_KEY
GROUP BY IBPD.session_key, IBPD.handle) hc
ON hc.session_key = bpd.SESSION_KEY
```

the query completes in under 17 seconds, while including the inner join with temporary table hc results in the query completing in 5 minutes
Running frequently even causes

```
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
```

I have tried adding `/*+ use_hash(bpd hc) */` and `/*+ use_hash(ibpd rbsd) */` as hints to force using hash join instead of nested loops but the problem persists.

It's also not clear why the query plan shows left outer joins with recid column when I don't try to join using it.

Can someone throw some light on the query plan?

Answer (score 3):

With dictionary queries, you are hitting a bunch of (sometimes complex views) and view merging can really wreak havoc on a plan. My suggestion with these, assuming you have the right joins and there aren't any many-to-many joins here, is to disable view merging (see the *two* lines of hints below, one in the subquery):

```
SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(bpd) NO_MERGE(bsjd) NO_MERGE(bsd) */
      bpd.handle,
       bpd.media,
       bpd.copy#,
       bpd.bytes,
       bpd.session_key,
       bsjd.operation,
       bsjd.start_time,
       bsjd.end_time,
       bpd.completion_time,
       bsd.controlfile_included
  FROM v$backup_piece_details bpd
   INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details bsjd
                  ON bpd.SESSION_KEY = bsjd.session_key
   INNER JOIN v$backup_set_details bsd
                  ON bpd.set_stamp = bsd.set_stamp
                     AND bpd.set_count = bsd.set_count
   INNER JOIN (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE NO_MERGE(ibpd rbsd) */
                     ibpd.session_key,
                     COUNT (ibpd.handle) COUNT
                FROM v$backup_piece_details ibpd
                 INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details rbsd
                                ON IBPD.session_key = rbsd.SESSION_KEY
            GROUP BY IBPD.session_key,
                     IBPD.handle) hc
                  ON hc.session_key = bpd.SESSION_KEY
```

Secondly, it is sometimes necessary to gather fixed object stats (`dbms_stats.gather_fixed_objects_stats`).

Comment: Hi Paul, so to summarise oracle automatically does some kind of cartesian join/merge for these in the background?

Comment: With v$ views joined together it seems to be very inclined to merge the views and it just has a hard time making good decisions about join order. I speak from decades of experience monitoring Oracle and hitting v$ views pretty hard. I've pretty much arrived at a rule that I always put a NO_MERGE hint on every dictionary view I hit if I'm joining it to another one.

Comment: Oh, I should clarify: when I say "merge" I do not mean sort-merge as a join method. I mean view merging, which is a different concept and is a type of query rewrite.

Comment: Hi Paul, using ORDERED has actually improved the query speed a lot, also is this the view merging you mean https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/post/optimizer-transformations-view-merging-part-1

Comment: Yes, that's view merging. ORDERED can be dangerous against performance views, as their FROM clauses are not always in the order you want. You may have gotten lucky and it turned out useful at the moment, but I never use ORDERED against dictionary views. If you have to force the order between them, use LEADING.

Comment: yup seems like I have gotten lucky https://pastebin.com/KzE55Xqx, https://pastebin.com/LRcdSAd3 just leaving the query plans here for leading and ordered, LEADING caused temp space issue, I guess giving merge hint sort of reduced the temp space issue but I am going to take your advice and not use this maybe just split the query and write stuff to save me from the pain

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to your views so cannot test whether this would give the same output but you could try using an analytic `COUNT` function so that you do not need to join the tables a second time:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       bsd.controlfile_included
FROM   ( SELECT bpd.handle,
                bpd.media,
                bpd.copy#,
                bpd.bytes,
                bpd.session_key,
                bsjd.operation,
                bsjd.start_time,
                bsjd.end_time,
                bpd.completion_time,
                COUNT(bpd.handle) OVER (PARTITION BY bpd.session_key, bpd.handle)
                  AS handle_count,
                bpd.set_stamp
         FROM   v$backup_piece_details bpd 
                INNER JOIN v$rman_backup_subjob_details bsjd
                ON bpd.SESSION_KEY = bsjd.session_key
       ) s
       INNER JOIN v$backup_set_details bsd
       ON ( s.set_stamp = bsd.set_stamp AND s.set_count = bsd.set_count )
```

> It's also not clear why the query plan shows left outer joins with `recid` column when I don't try to join using it.

A `VIEW` is just a query with a pre-defined SQL statement. When you query from a view then Oracle's SQL engine will rewrite your statement to select from the underlying tables that the view queries and if the statement the view is based on uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on a `recid` column then the execution plan will show that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `recid` column between the underlying tables when you query that view. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6VwZs_7u)

Comment: Hi MT0, Thanks for answering, say I use a CTE any chance I get better performance?

Comment: @AAB If the analytic function works then there is no need to try to materialize any sub-queries (which is, I assume, why you are suggesting a sub-query factoring clause, a.k.a. CTE) as you will not be selecting from any tables multiple times. If you are using your code then you can always try it and see (if you can materialize the appropriate part of the query that is being reused).

Comment: I will be using the results from this to join another v$ view, have not checked how it will perform, but yes the analytic function seems like the best way ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree what said about the hint and the statistics but it seems there is another issue becuase of the error `ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP`. this error means the data you are selecting has bigger size then on tablespace temp, what you should do either select few data or increase the tablespace . you can split the query to two

Comment: Hi Moudiz I agree but the issue why passing a hint say ordered for the same query yields a better result and causes no temp space issues